# Accessing the Network Panel Data on Google Chrome Developer Tools using Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-chrome-devtools

I have been provided the following code to allow me to access the Network Panel Data on Google Chrome Developer Tools in order to be able to get this information while running my Selenium scripts.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
String scriptToExecute = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();
System.out.println(netData);
```

However my Automation Framework is written in Ruby, how would I convert the above to work in my Ruby Environment? Are there any additional Gems I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selenium API is pretty similar among its implementations, so, although I haven't tested it, offhand I think the following would work:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
puts(driver.title)
script = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;"
data = driver.execute_script(script)
puts data
```

You would also have to install the Selenium gem. You can see their [official instructions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) about this.